# If $\| g_k\|_1 \leq 2^{-k}$ for every $k\geq1$, then $(g_k)_k$ converges to zero a.e

Tags: real-analysis

I intuitively understand why it converges to zero a.e. But I don't know how to prove this using $\epsilon$.
Please help me prove this question using  $\epsilon$.

Question:
If $\| g_k\|_1 \leq 2^{-k}$ for every $k\geq1$, then $(g_k)_k$ converges to zero almost everywhere.

What I tried:

$\| g_k\|_1 = \int |g_k|\leq 2^{-k}$ for every k.

I want to show that, given any $\epsilon >0$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $k>N$ we have $|g_k-0|<\epsilon$.

And... I have no clue.

Should I take integral over the inequality ? or any advice?

Comment: Observe that $2^{-k}$ is a summable sequence, as such, the series $|g_k|$ belongs to $\mathscr{L}^1,$ _a fortiori_ $g_k \to 0.$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: MCT applied to $\int (\sum g_k).$

Comment: Monotone Convergence Theorem, if you're not sure

Answer (score 1):

Of course, we can use the monotone convergence theorem to solve the problem, but a more “hands-on” approach can be done, using only more basic measure-theoretical properties.

Let $S_k=\{|g_k| \geq 2^{-k/2}\}$. By Markov inequality, $S_k$ has measure at most $2^{-k/2}$. Thus the sum of the measures of the $S_k$ converge.

By Borel-Cantelli, it follows that almost every $x$ is in finitely many $S_k$.

Now, if $x$ is in finitely many $S_k$, then for all large enough $k$, $|g_k(x)| \leq 2^{-k/2}$ and thus $g_k(x) \rightarrow 0$.